# items are repeated in SAP B1 query

Tags: sapb1

Below query is giving me correct output on quantity (but have to add quantities of repeated styles) but item code and item description is repeated. i want to see one time code having Total PO qty and what in stock.

Can you please advise what's wrong with this query.

Thanks

Shahzad Ahmed [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AGlXr.jpg)

```
SELECT 
T1.[ItemCode], 
T1.[Dscription], 
sum(T1.[Quantity]) as 'PO QTY', 
T3.[OnHand] 

FROM 

ORDR T0  INNER JOIN RDR1 T1 ON T0.[DocEntry] = T1.[DocEntry] 
INNER JOIN OITM T2 ON T1.[ItemCode] = T2.[ItemCode] 
INNER JOIN OITW T3 ON T2.[ItemCode] = T3.[ItemCode] 

WHERE

 T0.[CardCode] = 'c00192' and
    T0.[NumAtCard]  Like '818276%%'  and
    T3.[WhsCode] = '161' 

GROUP BY T1.[ItemCode], T1.[Dscription], T1.[Quantity],  T3.[OnHand]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to remove T1.[Quantity] from your `GROUP BY`. You should read on how to use a Group by, but to summarize, when you're calling a group by, you're asking to look for rows with the same values in some columns.

For exemple, here you want to add the quantities of every row with the same ItemCode, Dscription, OnHand, but you're asking to also look for rows with the same Quantity here.

Here is a good article on [GROUP BY](https://www.w3resource.com/sql/aggregate-functions/sum-with-group-by.php)

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. one more help. in where clause NumatCard has a unique number init but contains store# with a -. like 818276-03004 and i have almost 60 stores. can i provide numatcard(only of PO#) as my input condition?

Comment: Sadly, i'm not sure the understand the question. As i understand, NumAtCard is in fact a unique number, a "-" and a store number. So you're asking if you could do a query where you look for a certain PO in NumAtCard. Is the PO the store's number? So in your example your PO would be 03004? And don't forget to mark the answer as the solution so other users will know where to look!

Comment: PO# is 818276. but once we receive PO though EDI this PO is segregated by store#(03004 is a store#). so for every store separate SO is generated in SAP having Numatcard as 818276-03004, 818276-03005 and so on. that's why i put condition in where clause that numatcard starts with 818276. now i want this PO#(818276) in input field to run a query.

Comment: Yes you can do this with parameters! Just turn your like clause to NumAtCard Like param and in input give param value. Be sure to add the '%' so you'll have every stores for this PO

Comment: Thanks Fleury26 for you prompt help. really appreciate.

Comment: T0.[NumAtCard] like '[%0]' + '%%'  that's what i required while giving input parameter. thanks